# Score calculation from array values

Tags: javascript

As the title suggests. How do I do this?

Im bound to use pure JS, and i'm realy new to it (like realy realy new). So please excuse my noob question. :)

My array looks like this :

```
var questionArr = [
{
    'questionId' : 'Question1',
    'question' : 'Q1: How many Objects are there? ',
    'choices' : [
        {"id" : "10", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
        {'id' : "11", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
        {'id' : "12", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
        {'id' : "15", "tf" : true, "points" : 10},
        {'id' : "16", "tf" : false, "points" : 0}
    ],
    'Mchoice' : false,
    'completed' : false
},
{
    'questionId' : 'Question2',
    'question' : 'Q2: some Question will go here? ',
    'choices' : [
            {'id' : "answer1", "tf" : true, "points" : 5},
            {'id' : "answer2", "tf" : false, "points" : 1},
            {'id' : "answer3", "tf" : false, "points" : 1},
            {'id' : "answer4", "tf" : true, "points" : 10}
        ],
        'Mchoice' : true,
        'completed' : false
    },
```

and ongoing.

For each the choices are displayed as radio buttons or checkboxes. Depending on "Mchoice" beeing false/true. When i create them, each of them gets the value of "tf" that i can check if the selected answer is the correct or not.

My goal is to get the score calculated in the background, adding the points up if the answer is correct, and subtract the points if the answer is wrong, but i cant go below 0 when subtracting. After all questions are answered and i press the submit button i want to see how many out of the total number of points for each question were achieved. Something like X out of 10 for question 1 and than also at the end of the page something Total score: X out of 100. lets just say 100 would be the total number of points that could be achieved.

I hope you know what i mean and can help me, because im realy stuck on this for a day or more now. No idea how to achieve this. Again, im realy new to JS, so please dont be to harsh on me if this is a realy stupid question in the end :)

Comment: use nested loop for this once you achieve this array.

Comment: it's pretty simple, but how will you know which choice did user selected?

Comment: if MChoice means the user's answer is correct or not, i see multiple correct answers there, so how to know exactly which answer did user select

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < questionArr.length; i++) {
    var obj = questionArr [i];
    for(var j = 0; j < obj.choices.length; j++) { do your sum here}
    console.log(obj.id);
}

Comment: @AbdulJabbar MChoice just determins if the question would be a Multiple choice Question or a single choice one, determining the option to select an answer from radio buttons or checkboxes. i was thinking about something like this.value, but not sure if that would go in the right direction

Comment: @AbdulJabbar i made a fiddle of what i got so far, i hope that helps you when you see the whole thing http://jsfiddle.net/11w6Lzjy/

Comment: check my answer and fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it's not a stupid question. You need to have the selected choices, you can check them one by one or store them first in an array then calculate score (like i did):

```
var questionArr = [
    {
        'questionId' : 'Question1',
        'question' : 'Q1: How many Objects are there? ',
        'choices' : [
            {"id" : "10", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
            {'id' : "11", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
            {'id' : "12", "tf" : false, "points" : 0},
            {'id' : "15", "tf" : true, "points" : 10},
            {'id' : "16", "tf" : false, "points" : 0}
        ],
        'Mchoice' : false,
        'completed' : false
    },
    {
        'questionId' : 'Question2',
        'question' : 'Q2: some Question will go here? ',
        'choices' : [
                {'id' : "answer1", "tf" : true, "points" : 5},
                {'id' : "answer2", "tf" : false, "points" : 1},
                {'id' : "answer3", "tf" : false, "points" : 1},
                {'id' : "answer4", "tf" : true, "points" : 10}
            ],
            'Mchoice' : true,
            'completed' : false
    }
]
var selectedChoicesArray = ["10", "answer4"] //choices that user selected as answers
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i<questionArr.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<questionArr[i].choices.length; j++){
        if(questionArr[i].choices[j].id == selectedChoicesArray[i]) //the choice which user selected
            sum += questionArr[i].choices[j].points //matched choice's points will be added to the sum
    }
}
alert("Sum: "+sum);
```

in this case, as selectedChoicesArray presents, user selected first choice for question1 and fourth choice for answer 2, hence, the sum will be 10! if you change it to:

```
var selectedChoicesArray = ["15", "answer1"];
```

sum will be 15 in this case. Hopefully you'll understand those loops they're fairly straightforward.

**[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/85bkfaqh/)**

Comment: and if you want to check and add the sum as the user selects (one at a time) then it will be done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/85bkfaqh/2/

Comment: wow, this is awesome. Thanks alot for this. Its not as complicated as i thought, i realy am just a beginner and thought this be a way bigger code and more complicated. You realy did save me there ;)